# pass ID from grid view in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I try to get `ID` from grid view . IN grid view there is data from another table and the data in `linq` query is from another table . so there is `ID` in both table .. `MID` in `table1` and `ID` in table2`(which is in grid view e.g. <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/> )` .. i get `ID` from grid view now i try to get data on behalf of this `ID` from another table so how to pass `ID` from grid view in `linq`

i try this

```
protected void GridView1_select(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

            string ID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text.TrimEnd();
          GetVoiliations(Convert.ToInt32(ID));

        }

    }

[WebMethod]
    public static string GetVo(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            T1 DB = new T1();
            string data = "[";
            data+="ID:'"+ID+"',";
            var re = (from veh in DB.tblV
                      join reg in DB.tblr on veh .MID equals reg.ID  
                    where reg.ID==ID  && !(vehvoila.VName == "")
                      group veh by veh .VName into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = g.Key,
                          cnt = g.Select(t => t.Name).Count()
                      }).ToList();


            data += re.ToList().Select(x => "['" + x.Name + "'," + x.cnt + "]")
              .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);

            data += "]";


            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }

    }


   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_select"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="Owner Name"/> 
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**update**
JSON

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var strArray = "[['aasd', 9],['Kiasdwi', 3],['Grapasdes (bunch)', 1]]";

    $(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo", // the method we are calling
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: $('#ID').val() }),

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                alert(result.d);
                //start
                strArray = result.d;
                var myarray = eval(strArray);
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 45
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            innerSize: 100,
                            depth: 45
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Delivered amount',
                        data: myarray
                    }]
                });

                //end
            }
        });

  });

        </script>
```

data in alert box is

```
[ID:'1',['SSAFTER',1],[' Belt',4]
```

when i click on select from grid view i got data in alert box i write alert box in json just for test whether i get correct data or not now  i got data what i want but high chart is not display?

any solution?

Comment: whats the error occured

Comment: you get exact Id in this line    string ID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text.TrimEnd();

Comment: there is no error..actually i try to get data on highchart..  when i click on select whole data is display on chart .. where as i want specific data according to ID on highchart.. i use pie chart.

Comment: yes i know i get exact ID. but i don't get data according to ID

Comment: what GetVoiliations() method do?

Comment: just pass the id to method GetVoiliations(ID); and get the record there

Comment: GetVoiliations() do select data from table1  and then i pass this method in json for get data in chart..

Comment: this shows error:Error 2 No overload for method 'GetVoiliations' takes 1 arguments

Comment: change the public static string GetVoiliations(string Id= null) and use this id in your code to get data from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should really think to the structure of your code, because the "all in one" methods make things complicated => one method to retrieve data, one to parse it into Json, at least.

And generate a Json string manually is... a little bit ugly, no ? Couldn't you use Json.Net or something similar ?

Anyway, you can either create a new method, with a filter on id (I don't know if Id is an int or a string in your db, change that if needed). But this would duplicate most of the acutal method code, which is never good.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetVoiliationsById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
           T1 DB = new T1();

           string data = "[";
           var re = (from ve in table1 i

                      where !(ve .VName == "") 
                      //add a new filter
                      && ve.Id == id
                      group ve by ve .VName into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = g.Key,
                          cnt = g.Select(t => t.Name).Count()
                      }).ToList();
            data += re.ToList().Select(x => "['" + x.Name + "'," + x.cnt + "]")
              .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
            data += "]";
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }

    }
```

or you could use a default parameter in your method

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetVoiliations(string id = null)
    {
        try
        {
        T1 DB = new T1();

        string data = "[";
       var re = (from ve in table1 i

                  where !(ve .VName == "")
                  //add new filter
                  && (id == null || ve.Id == id)
                  group ve by ve .VName into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Name = g.Key,
                      cnt = g.Select(t => t.Name).Count()
                  }).ToList();
        data += re.ToList().Select(x => "['" + x.Name + "'," + x.cnt + "]")
          .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
        data += "]";
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception();

    }

}
```

Then you could call `GetVoiliations(ID)` or `GetVoiliationsById(ID)`, and have the data filtered.

Comment: yes i edit getvol method before your post.. now please check update question

Comment: how i pass this ID on json? because this ID is from gridview .. i paste json please check